# How to keep precision for big numbers in golang when converting from float to big.Int

Tags: go

I have an input that could be a very big or a very small float and need to convert it to `big.Int`, but for some reason, there is some precision loss.
I understand that this should happen for very small numbers, but why does it happen for a big number, and how to avoid it?

https://go.dev/play/p/AySnKAikSRx

Comment: You have lost precision even before using the `big.Float` by trying to store the value in a `float64`

Answer (score 2):

All *positive integers* up to 9007199254740992 can be represented in a float64 without any loss of precision. Anything higher, you run the risk of precision loss, which is happening in your case.

---

To give a basic idea of why..

Say we're inventing an extremely compact scheme for representing floating point numbers using the following formula:

```
m.mm * 10^+-e
```

.. where:

- e = exponent, [1-9]
- m.mm = mantissa [0.01-9.99]

With this, we can figure out what range of values can be represented:

- lowest = 0.01 * 10^-9 = 0.00000000001
- highest = 9.99 * 10^9 = 9990000000

So that's a pretty decent range of numbers.

We can represent a fair few positive integers without any difficulty, e.g.

```
1   = 1.00 * 10^0
2   = 2.00 * 10^0
3   = 3.00 * 10^0
⋮
10  = 1.00 * 10^1
11  = 1.10 * 10^1
12  = 1.20 * 10^1
⋮
100 = 1.00 * 10^2
101 = 1.01 * 10^2
102 = 1.02 * 10^2
⋮
999 = 9.99 * 10^2
```

The problem starts when we exceed `9.99 * 10^2`. It's not an issue to represent 1000:

```
1000 = 1.00 * 10^3
```

But how do represent 1001? The next possible value is

```
1.01 * 10^3 = 1010
```

Which is +9 loss of precision, so we have to settle on `1.00 * 10^3` with -1 loss of precision.

The above is in essence how this plays out with float64, except in base 2 and with a 52 bit mantissa in play. With all 52 bits set, and then adding one, the value is:

```
1.0 * 2^53 = 9007199254740992
```

So all positive integers up to this value can be represented without precision loss. Integers higher than this *may* incur precision loss - it very much depends on the value.

---

Now, the value referenced in your Go code:

```
var x float64 = 827273999999999954
```

There is no way to represent this *exact value* as a float64.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x float64 = 827273999999999954

    fmt.Printf("%f\n", x)
}
```

yields..

```
827274000000000000.000000
```

So essentially precision is lost by the time `x` is initialized. But when does that occur? If we run..

```
$ go build -o tmp
$ go tool objdump tmp
```

And search for `TEXT main.main(SB)`, we can find the instruction:

```
main.go:10            0x108b654               48b840d5cba322f6a643    MOVQ $0x43a6f622a3cbd540, AX
```

So `0x43a6f622a3cbd540` is being set into AX - this is our float64 value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("float: %f\n", math.Float64frombits(0x43a6f622a3cbd540))
}
```

prints

```
float: 827274000000000000.000000
```

So the precision has essentially been lost at compile time (which makes sense). So on the line of code with `big.NewFloat(x).Int(nil)`, the value being passed as `x` is `827274000000000000.000000`

---

> how to avoid it?

With the code you've provided, there is no way.

If you're able to represent the value as an integer..

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    var x uint64 = 827273999999999954

    bf := (&big.Float{}).SetUint64(x)
    
    fmt.Println(bf)
}
```

yields

```
8.27273999999999954e+17
```

which is the value you're expecting. Or alternatively via a string:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    var x string = "827273999999999954"

    bf, ok := (&big.Float{}).SetString(x)
    if !ok {
        panic("failed to set string")
    }

    fmt.Println(bf)
}
```